# Why is the first letter of a proper noun capitalized

Tags: proper-nouns, capitalization

Is it incorrect grammar to make the first letter of a proper noun small letters ? 
I found that most of the online grammar checkers will mark it as an error if you don't 
capitalize the first letter of a proper noun. What's the logic behind that.

Comment: The "logic" is that proper nouns are capitalized in English. That's the rule. Could you clarify what exactly you'd like to know? (There are exceptions and edge cases, but they don't seem relevant here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have noticed that May is the name of a month and a girl's name, but it is also a verb, a modal verb to be precise.
Capitalising proper nouns avoids possible ambiguity or confusion. Compare "rolling stones" and the "Rolling Stones", the first is an activity the latter is the name of a well-known rock band.

In the 17th and 18th century, English used to capitalise nouns that were considered important or significant, but not everyone agreed which nouns were important and which were not. Until a certain Thomas Dyche, in 1764,  wrote:

> 1. Let *Proper Names* of *Persons* *Places*, *Ships Rivers*, &c. be always distinguished by the beginning with a *Capital*, or *great Letter*.
> 2. ’Tis esteem'd Ornamental to begin any *Substantive* in the Sentence with a *Capital*, if it bear some *considerable Stress* of the Author's *Sense* upon it, to make it the more *remarkable* and *conspicuous*.
>    "'*Tis grown Customary in Printing to begin every* Substantive *with a* Capital, *but in my Opinion 'tis unnecessary, and hinders that remarkable* Distinction *intended by a* Capital".

[A Guide to the English Tongue in Two Parts](https://books.google.it/books?id=cSrdPQvBuhIC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22Tis%20grown%20Customary%20in%20Printing%20to%20begin%20every%20Substantive%22&source=bl&ots=QuauaP_fKQ&sig=ACfU3U1MLTmA5qchLOMyE85IxzjJOJQABg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjug5rTjKjvAhW7wAIHHaLJBCgQ6AEwAXoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=%22Tis%20grown%20Customary%20in%20Printing%20to%20begin%20every%20Substantive%22&f=false)

Note the author's idiosyncratic use of italics and capital letters, which appears to contradict, somewhat, his provided guidelines.

Comment: That was really cool explanation. So if I am writing as in month I will write `May` as a verb `may` and `May` if I was referring to a name of a person

Comment: @Amitwadhwa   Your summary is absolutely correct. 

Answer (score 0):

**Proper noun definition:** A proper noun is any person, place or thing. A proper noun refers to anything or concept that is particular or specific.

What is a Proper Noun?

What are proper nouns? A proper noun is any noun that names anything specific. Therefore, a proper noun is any particular name of a person, place, or thing. **Proper nouns are always capitalized.**

Examples of Proper Nouns:

Cathy (specific name of person)
London (specific name of place)
Spot (specific name of thing)

[Proper noun definition:](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/proper-noun)

Comment: **Spot** are you sure?

Comment: @RonaldSole Spot the dog

Comment: @PrimeMover Maybe, but dogs are not typically referred to as things. They’re usually  pets if they’re named.

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe to you. Not everyone appreciates dogs.

Comment: @PrimeMover Well, I would point out the confusion referring to a pet as a thing instead of a pet caused in the previous comment. How do you know Spot isn’t a fish?

Comment: @ColleenV It was merely an example of Spot being used as a proper noun. It's one of the more common tropes and/or memes in the literature of small children: a dog named Spot. RonaldSole was clearly confused as to why Spot was considered a proper name. I answered with a commonly-understood example.

Comment: @Brad Sorry to stir things up! 'twas more mischief than confusion.

Comment: @PrimeMover So you're OK with the idea that "Spot" is typically a dog, but not OK with the idea that people typically don't refer to pets as "things"? Or you are OK with it, so long as the pet isn't a dog because you don't like dogs?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it incorrect grammar to make the first letter of a proper noun small letters ?

Short answer - yes, according to the rules of the English language. Proper nouns - unique names of people, places, or one-of-a-kind items - are always capitalised.

The only exception to this would be if writing in *block capitals*, in which case *every* letter would be capitalised and the first letter would not be distinguishable from any other. This is common on signage, such as when the names of places are written on road signs.

There may be some comparable situations where, for entirely stylistic reasons, a proper noun may be written in lower-case letters, but this would be considered as a mistake unless it were clear that *only* lower-case letters were being used for stylistic reasons. Even in such a case, it might be thought of as a *deliberate* mistake.

Of course, some words which are proper nouns may also be used in other contexts as common nouns. A good example are the compass directions, which are common nouns because every place on earth has 'a north', but may also be used with a country to refer specifically to a region, ie '*the* North'.